# Do I need separate rows for each patient for different covariates in a regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic

patient  outcome_var   covar1 covar2 covar3 
1          y                1     0    0
1          y                0     0    1 
1          y                1     0    0
2          n                1     0    0
2          n                0     1    0
2          n                0     0    0

Do I need to use the table above as such in a logistic regression or for each patient bring a single observation for each covariate for example, make the above table look like this

patient  outcome_var     covar1 covar2 covar3 
1           y               1      0      1
2           n               1      1      0

i.e, to just bring a single observation for each covariate and get a single for each patient with a single 1/0 value for each covariate to use in a logistic regression model.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

How you structure your data depends on the type of analysis you're doing and the software you're using. If you are running a standard logistic regression predicting a single outcome at one time point from several covariates, you should have one row per patient. That row should contain all the information about a patient.

The first table would be used if you were taking different measurements at different times for each patient, and at each occasion, one of the covariates could be active. For example, in a sequential trial, you might give one treatment at time 1 and record the response to that treatment, then another treatment at time 2 and record the response to that treatment, etc. Then you would have one row per time point per patient. The key is that you are measuring the outcome multiple times; when you do this, you should have a row for each time the outcome is measured. You would fit a mixed effects logistic regression to this kind of data. You haven't indicated that your data are like this.

Comment: Thanks Noah for the answer. I am doing a standard multiple logistic regression in R. so, I think I should do one patient per line with all the covariates in different columns on a single line. Thats what I have done but I wasn't sure. When I run the model there is quite a big difference in coefficients values for many covariates between the univariate model outcome and multivariate. I read if there is a big difference then it means that you have dependent variables.